# SQL Query to remove EEID from each cell in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2019

I use Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio and I have a table that includes employee names along with their Employee ID and some have only names w/o Employee ID (EEID). What I want to get is a query that remove any EEID (if any) and keep Employee Name only. Can anyone help? I'm new to SQL and trying to learn here.
Below is a sample table along with details:

Table Name: HR_Mod_Mgemt
Column Name: Name - Level 02

Table Details:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rv4PL.png)

Thank you!

Comment: Please post your data/structure inline not in screen shots.

Comment: How can I post the data structure here? I have the table name which is (HR_Mod_Mgemt) and the Column Name which is (Name - Level 02) and the data under this column are:

 AA BB (12345678)
 BB (23456789)
 NULL
 CC DD
 DD EE (34567891)
 EE (45678911)
 F. (56789112)
 NULL